# What is the purpose of Java DOT operator?

Tags: java

Can somebody tell me what Java DOT operator actually does?

For example:

```
public class {
    int value;
    public void great() {};
    ... 
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person p = new Person();

    Person.great(); // <--- here

    Person.value; // <--- here
```

I want to know what is **`.`** operator doing in above code when I do `Person.great()` or `Person.value`?

Answer (score 5):

The dot operator, also known as separator or period used to separate a variable or method from a reference variable.

Only static variables or methods can be accessed using class name.

Code that is outside the object's class must use an object reference or expression, followed by the dot (.) operator, followed by a simple field name as in

```
objectReference.fieldName
```

We use the object reference to invoke an object's method. Append the method's simple name to the object reference, with an intervening dot operator (.) as in

```
objectReference.methodName(argumentList);
```

In the above mentioned code, ***p.great()*** can be used to invoke the method ***great()*** on object ***p*** and ***p.value*** is used to access the instance variable ***value***.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

The Complete Reference, Book by Herbert Schildt

Answer (score 1):

`.` is not an operator. Therefore, it "does" nothing.

It is just a syntactic element that denotes the seperation of, in this case, a variable name holding an object and the object's property. The same character is used to seperate package names and Classes.

Comment: It is the correct answer though - if you were not looking for this, maybe rephrase your question. There realls isn't much more to be said about that `.` - it has not much more functionality than a `.` in English has. In English, `.` seperates two sentences. In Java, it seperates the variable name and the property name. It tells the tokenizer (a part of the compiler) that the variable names stops there and the next character is the beginning of a property name. That's it.

Comment: If you actually want to know how the compiler works, or how the object is stored in memory so the properties can be retrieved, or what instructions will end up being in the cimpiled bytecode - that is a whole different story, a completely different quesiton, and WAY too complex to be easily answered on SO. I recommend reading books on the java engine in this case.

Comment: . is certainly an operator. It is a binary operator. The left operand resolves to some module in the program and the right hand resolves to  a submodule of the left hand. It has left-to-right associativity so that System.out.println is (System.out).println as opposed to System.(out.println), and it has the highest operator precendence so that obj1.prop1+obj2.prop2 is (obj1.prop1)+(obj2.prop2) as opposed to obj1.(prop1+obj2).prop2. It is listed in the Java docs as an operator, it is listed on operator precedents charts as an operator, and it is built into the grammar as an operator.

Answer (score 1):

Simply the dot operator acts as an access provider for objects and classes. The usage of the above operator is as below.

It separates a function and variable from an instance variable.
It allows accessing sub-packages and classes from a package.
It leads to access to the member of a class or a package.

```
public class DotOperatorExample1 {
        
void display() { 
        double d = 67.54;    
        int i = (int)d;  
        System.out.println(i);  
    }  
public static void main(String args[]) {  
        DotOperatorExample1 doe = new DotOperatorExample1();   
        doe.display();
    }  
}
```