# cannot append to my array during a for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently learning JAVA using Aleks Rudenko book, and as a newbie in JAVA I still cannot figure out simple compilation errors. I tried to create a simple code that takes an array X and multiply every single term of it by Y. Finally, the array*Y should be printed out as follows:

```
   public class CurrencyConverter {   
       double[] answers = new double[] {};
       public double[] Times2 (double[] x, double y) {
           for (int i=1; i<x.length+1;i++) {
             answers.add(x[i]*y);
           }
       return answers;
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       CurrencyConverter cc = new CurrencyConverter();
       double [] rates= new double[] {63,3.0,3.0,595.5,18.0,107.0,2.0,0.0};
       System.out.println(cc.Times2(rates,2));
       } 
    }
```

the error message is

```
error: cannot find symbol
                 answers.add(x[i]*y);
                        ^
  symbol:   method add(double)
  location: variable answers of type double[]
1 error
```

I cannot figure out what is the reason for this compilation error. Thanks for the help !

Comment: You are using `.` `dot` operator on an array. `answers` is an array and its values can be accessed like `answers[0] -> first element` or `answers[n] -> gives n element`. Had `answers` been an object with say a property called `status`, then you would access `status` from `answers` as `answers.status` .

Comment: Similar if `answers` have method say `bestAnswer()` then you would access it as `answers.bestAnswer()`

Comment: (added a bit more detailed answer below as comments have characters limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**add** is not defined for arrays. If you want to add elements, use List.

There are several ways to fix your code:

a) use List:

```
import java.util.*;

List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

public List<Double> Times2 (double[] x, double y) {
    for (int i=0; i<x.length;i++) {
      list.add(x[i]*y);
    }
    return list;
}
```

b) Don't add elements, just write them into array:

```
double[] answers;

public double[] Times2 (double[] x, double y) {
    answers = new double[x.length];
    for (int i=0; i<x.length;i++) {
      answers[i] = x[i]*y;
    }
    return answers;
}
```

..Also, watch out for the array index out of bounds. First element has index **0** and last item has index **length - 1**.

And one last thing, you will probably encounter problem with printing your results.
If you want to use list, use `System.out.println(cc.Times2(...).toString());` and if you want to use array, use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cc.Times2(...)));`

Comment: Probably ArrayList or Vector, not List

Comment: I generally recommend using List as it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a while loop, instead of a for loop, for this use case. And use a Vector:

```
   Vector<Object> answers = new Vector<Object>();
```

Comment: Don't use `Vector`, unless you actually need the synchronization. Use `ArrayList`.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, for this one, either Vector or ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in java don't have any methods. You access stuff by index.  Your code should look

```
public static class CurrencyConverter {

    public double[] Times2(double[] x, double y) {
        double[] answers = new double[x.length];
        for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
            answers[i] = x[i] * y;
        }
        return answers;
    }

}
```

Notice that the for loop starts with i as 0. the first index of an array is always 0, not 1.  the answers array is init'ed inside the method as it's best to keep variables hidden (scoped) from things that don't need them.  it's also init'ed with the size it needs to be.

Some of the other answers here say to use stuff based on [java.util.AbstractCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html).  While you could but there's no good reason for extra overhead for something simple like this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.` **[dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646364/java-dot-operator-what-it-actually-does)** operator on an *array*. `answers` is an array and its values can be accessed like `answers[0]` -> *first element* or `answers[9]` -> gives *9th element*. Had answers been an object with say a variable called `status`, then you would access status from answers as `answers.status`

Similar if answers have method say `bestAnswer()` then you would access it as `answers.bestAnswer()`

And if you want to hold a bunch of objects of your custom type `Answer` in an array then you would instantiate each `Answer` object first and add it to the array `answers` array as:

```
Answer firstAnswer = Answer(); 
Answer secondAnswer = Answer();
...

answers[0] = firstAnswer;
answers[1] = secondAnswer;
...
```